# Possible to have world node only affect one object? Problem with lightning Volume Absorption

Tags: node-editor, lighting, volumetrics, world

Is it possible to have a world node that only affects an object with volume absorption?
I have a situation where I want to be able to control the lighting specifically for the liquid. I have tried light linking, but it doesn't seem to work for me at all.

Let me know if I'm unclear and need to explain better. I can also upload the model if necessary. The material 'above' the liquid is plastic